# Difference between () => someFunc and someFunc

Tags: reactjs, function, components

I have a react component

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  const someFunc = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <button onClick = {() => someFunc}>Button 1</button>
      <button onClick = {someFunc}>Button 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What is the difference between callings `onClick = {() => someFunc}` and `onClick = {someFunc}` . Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Did you mean `() => someFunc()`?

Comment: Assuming by `() => someFunc`, you meant `() => someFunc()`. The problem with this `() => someFunc()` syntax is that a different callback is created each time the `App` renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClick = {() => someFunc}
```

This is just returning the reference to `someFunc` when the onClick handler will run. This will not do anything (will not work how you expect).

```
onClick = {someFunc}
```

This is passing a direct reference to `someFunction` which will get called when the onClick handler is called. You can think of putting `someFnnction`'s body here as it is like this

```
onClick = {() => {
    console.log('clicked');
  }}
```